# Display Record Details in a Table/Grid using Crystal Report

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm currently working with Crystal Report 13 (Visual Studio 2010) with C# and I want to display a record details like below:

[image: Product Details]

I want each data to grow automatically so I set the property 'Can Grow' to True. The problem is they're overlapping each other. Preferably, I want to display the data in a table/grid if possible as this can't be achieved by using Line Object.

Comment: What do you mean by "line object"?

Comment: It's a tool that's available in the Toolbox to draw a line. It's also available when right clicking the section ("Insert Line")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the section and then click Section below.

Insert 3 sub section after main detail section

[image: Crystal Report Grid view]

try this it will work.

Comment: I have tried this way and it works like a charm. Thanks Asif for your great explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick the section on the right and click **Insert section below**. Then then put each field in a separate section. Use the draw line to draw the table, row and column borders. Your table cells will be able to grow and will not overlap over the line border. I do tables like this and it works for me.

Alternatively you could try to use a cross tab.

[image]

Comment: I can't find the option "Insert new line" as you described, what version of Crystal Reports that you have? However I see there's only "Insert Line" option which we can use to draw a line object, when I use this line object and my datas grow, they will overlap the line.